# Retrieve Entire Email (headers + all body parts) with PHP

Tags: php

I found this script:

http://code.google.com/p/php-mime-mail-parser/

It does a much better job parsing the email than what I have concocted for one of my projects over the last year.

For this to work though, the input needs to be the raw text of the email, the entire header and body parts. I have not found a PHP imap function that returns the entire email.

Do you know of one, or is their a way to piece it together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[imap_fetchheader](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchheader.php) can be used to retrieve the entire raw header and [imap_body](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-body.php) returns the entire body.